# simplexml pagination

Tags: pagination, simplexml

Here is the api i'm pulling from:
http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=p4t8BFcLDtCzpxdS&location=Houston,Tx&sort_order=popularity&date=future

All is fine, except I'm stumped on pagination.

The current page number and the total number of pages is provided in the xml. Now i'm just not sure how to paginate from it.